# Why is the present tense used in "Last year he's MVP"?

Tags: american-english, present-tense

Why is the last sentence in the passage below, "Last year he's MVP", written in the present tense?

> 'Hey, Ding Dong,' he calls. 'Who won the ball game?' 
> 'Brooklyn wins it in a romp, fourteen to three.' 
> 'Yeah? Great. Who pitched for Brooklyn?' 
> 'How-d'ya-call-it? I forget his name. How-d'ya-call-it.' 
> 'Oh, Howdoyacallit pitched! He's a good pitcher, that Howdoyacallit. Last year he's MVP.'
>
> — *A Portrait of a Young Man Drowning* by Charles Perry

Comment: The contraction for "he was" is also "he's"

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson No, it is not. There's no contraction for "he was."

Comment: You'll find that that quoted section gives an example. Another: "She's here yesterday, gone today. I wonder if she was in any pain." -- Patricia Anne Phillips, *Last Bride Standing*

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson You should post that as the answer. "He's" is pronounced /hiːʌs/ or /hiːəs/ when it means "He was". Likewise, /ʃiːʌs/ or /ʃiːəs/ for "she was".

Comment: @Greybeard I can't find any dictionary that lists "he's" as a contraction for "he was"; I certainly wouldn't use it that way.

Comment: @ alphabet: absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. I was born in an area that had the dialect /hiːʌs/, /ʃiːʌs/ version. Unfortunately, there are few written examples that are unambiguous. (I dare say DH Lawrence used it more than once in his mining series.)

Comment: Contractions don't get in dictionaries, and the ones that do aren't really contractions any more. Are _wanna, gotta, hafta, useta,_ and _lotta_ in your dictionaries?

Comment: The issue isn't whether "he's" is a dictionary-approved contraction for "he was" certified with a signed note from the OED, but whether somebody in highly colloquial or slangy speech might use it. (I don't think "Howdoyacallit" is terribly standard either.) Doesn't seem implausible.

Comment: I wonder if you could provide a bit more of the passage, or even a picture of the page?

Comment: @Greybeard That's still different from how "he's" is usually pronounced ([hiz]) so I'm not sure why it would also be written as "he's."

Answer (score 3):

You *could* interpret this as a case of the historical present, in which the present tense is used when narrating past events. In this case, though, it's likely just the result of speaking very informally.

Comment: "Brooklyn wins it in a romp, fourteen to three" a few lines previous also seems to be historical present.

Comment: @StuartF I seem to recall hearing someone call the historical present the "football coach tense."

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily present tense. The speaker could be using "he's" as a non-standard contraction of "he was" (if so, it might be pronounced slightly differently to convey this), along the same lines as the non-standard "Howdoyacallit".

According to comments by Greybeard on the OP,  "He's" would be pronounced /hiːʌs/ or /hiːəs/ when it means "He was". Likewise, /ʃiːʌs/ or /ʃiːəs/ for "she was"

See also another example from Patricia Anne Phillips in *Last Bride Standing* where "she's" is used in the past tense:

> She's here yesterday, gone today. I wonder if she was in any pain.

(Similar to your selection, that selection is also a character's speech and may reflect non-standard usage by that character)